# what is the exact meaning of ping -A

Tags: networking, ping

```
-A     Adaptive ping. Interpacket interval adapts to round-trip time, so that effectively not more than one (or more, if  preload  is set)  unanswered  probe  is  present in the network. Minimal interval is 200msec for not super-user. On networks with low rtt this mode is essentially equivalent to flood mode.
```

This is what i had seen in ping manual page what this means exactly please explain me in simple terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, ping requests are sent across the network at a set interval, usually 1 second. This is configurable with the -i flag. Generally, this means a full ping request and response occurs, then the tool does nothing for the rest of that second. In extremely bad network conditions, a new ping request could go out before the last one is returned.

Adaptive ping (-A) tries to adjust the interval to the RTT of the network link. This way, on average, a new ping request goes out as soon as the last reply is received.

Both of these are in contrast to flood mode, which sends out as many requests as possible with no delay or attention to the RTT.

Comment: That means the -A option is a flood mode.

Comment: Not exactly. Flood mode sends request continuously, adaptive times requests to match the return of the response. On very fast networks this might behave similar to flood, but on very slow networks it will not.